# How to Maintain the HTML5 Video Aspect Ratio according to Div Size

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am using react with typescript. In my project, I have JSON data that contains the information of the faces detected on the video. Now I am creating bounding boxes on faces in the video, but I am facing one problem is that the bounding box information is for the video resolution 3840 x 2160, but my div has `height` is `500px` and `width` is `800px` and I am also using `object-fill` property as `fill`. Now when I am rendering the bounding boxes on video it displays out from the div.

How to do this so that bounding boxes display an accurate position on the div.

sample JSON data look like this:

```
[
  { "frame": 2, "x": 2943, "y": 503, "width": 266, "height": 354 }

]
```

and my code:

```
<div ref={divRef}>
        <Video videoSource={source} ref={vRef}/>
        <svg id="svg" ref={sRef}>
        }
        </svg>
      </div>
```

Comment: Please show us code see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I updated the question and added my code as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something here, but it should be a simple math problem.

**1)** Get the height and width of the div that contains the video (500 X 800) .
**2)** See how many times it is smaller than the origin (3840 X 2160)

```
small video width / big video width = X ratio
    
small video height / big video height = Y ratio
```

Multiple X and Y values with these to find the right location at smaller video.

```
For frame 0, X should be : Old X * X aspect ratio

For frame 0, Y should be : Old Y * Y aspect ratio
```

That same logic goes for width and height. So you can loop through the JSON object to create a new object with expected values and map it in SVG.

Comment: Width -> width in json / div width

Comment: Should be my bad if I was confused with X and Y values there. What I meant here is to find the ratio for Y axis (height) and for X axis (width).

New height / old height = Ratio for Y axis. 
New width / old width = Ratio for X axis. 

Now, to find the new X value, you can multiple the old X value with ratio for X axis. 
To find the new Y value, multiple the old Y value with the ratio for Y axis. 
Same goes for width and height. 

Rest is is creating a loop to calculate the new values, assigning it to a new object and map through in the SVG like you did.

Comment: @SagharFrancis edited my answer. Should be better know as I eliminated the chance of me messing up with the number again =)